# How to reshape tensorflow tensor row-wise?

Tags: tensorflow

I have a tensorflow tensor -

```
a = [0,0,0,0,1,1]
```

How can I repeat `a` to get -

```
b = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1] # 8 times 0 and 2 times 1
```

I tried doing this by tiling the tensor row-wise and reshaping it -

```
X = tf.concat([[a],[a]], axis=0)
X = tf.reshape(X, [-1,2])
X = tf.reshape(X, [-1]) # assuming that reshape repeats each row
```

I have tried several variants of above, but I am ending with a tensor like below

```
b = [0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1]
```

I am missing some understanding of `tf.reshape`.

Answer (score 0):

A colleague just resolved my issue -

```
tf.reshape(tf.tile(a[:,None], [1,2]), [-1])
```

As per the behavior here, it seems that `tf.tile` and `tf.concat -> tf.reshape` do not have the same arrangement of elements in the memory.